# How to get a build recommendation for city after it was building wealth/research/culture?

Tags: civilization-4

Sometimes there's no recommendation for a building in a city, because it essentially has everything. So, I choose wealth, research or culture. Later, when I get a new tech, I want to cancel the wealth/research/culture build (easy enough to do - I just clear it in the queue). When I do this, the city effectively builds nothing, without going back to suggesting (recommending) a build. I'm obliged to pick something and wait for it to complete before I get a "recommendation" for the best build.

How can I get back to the recommended builds after wealth/research/culture, without having to build something arbitrarily?

Comment: Never experienced this before. I will try it out next time :). Do you have any of the expansions or only the plain Civ4?

Comment: @bazmegakapa I'm running only the plain Civ4 as far as I know. I can reproduce the problem at any time by simply choosing wealth/research/culture (I don't necessarily have to have "no suggestions", but that's the context where I pick wealth/research/culture).

Comment: Do you run the latest patch?

Comment: I'm running 1.7.4.0 @bazmegakapa

Comment: I'm a little rusty with Civ 4 and don't have a copy handy to check this for myself. Is the "recommended" next structure displayed as part of the construction completed dialog?

Comment: @bazmegakapa Civ 2 acted like this, and I believe Civ 1 too; it's not caused by mods or missing patches, it's just how the games have always acted after choosing wealth/research/culture.

Comment: You can empty the queue and turn on building automation to see what the top suggestion would be.

Comment: Finally I got a decent score on civ 4. Recommended builds are mostly useless I think, if you want to get a good score.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but if you go into the City View screen and tell it to not build anything (shift-click the build list in the bottom left), then I think when you exit the city screen it will pop up a list of recommended builds as normal.